# Maximizing ordered integer partitions 

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

The following question

$\quad$[Problem about expectation of maximum partial sum](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85409/problem-about-expectation-of-maximum-partial-sum):

can be reduced to determing
$$f(m,n) = \sum \max_{1\le i \le n}(x_1 + ... + x_i - \frac{m}{n} i)$$
where the sum is taken over all tuples $(x_1,...,x_n)$ of positive integers such that $x_1 + ... + x_n=m$.

Perhaps it's possible to evaluate this expression.

Comment: It would help others to follow the format. What is the actual question?  Are you asking for a closed form, upper or lower bounds, or a quick algorithm?  Please edit to specify.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.12

Comment: Tanks for your hint. Closed form would be perfect, an upper bound would also be very interesting. A (coarse) lower bound can be derived by counting those $x$ such that $x_1>m/n$. If I succeed, I'll post the lower bound later on and in this turn I'll specify the question in a better way. 